# DB2 Function Loop?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, db2

lets call it foo

I'll call it in the following way:

```
Select * From TABLE (schema.foo("aString"))
```

It will return a string of all the items related to that username.

EG

```
Select * From TABLE (schema.foo("apple")) = 

apple
-----
fruit
red
delicious
```

What I want to do is run through a list, and run the procedure against each row in that list.

What I'm trying to run:

```
Select * from schema.fruits where name in (Select * From TABLE (schema.foo(fruits.name))
```

Its not giving me the right output however. What I would want is the following:

```
apple  | fruit
apple  | red
apple  | delicious
orange | fruit
orange | orange
orange | also delicious
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Can you include your SP code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is basically saying the following:

> > Hey, for every `name` in `fruits`, get the output of function `foo()`, and then return data from only `fruits` if `name` is in the output.

Do you see the two problems here?

1. Your query expects that `foo` outputs the input again (unlikely, and problematic in some cases).
2. Data compared with the `IN` clause can't be `SELECT`ed - you get a Boolean (`true`/`false`) result.

Now, problem 2 could be easily solved by switching to a `JOIN` + subquery:

```
SELECT ...
FROM Schema.Fruits
JOIN (SELECT ...
      FROM TABLE (Foo(Fruits.name))) FooOut(descr)
ON ....
```

... because the output of the function is now not being used for a comparison directly, but present as other data/another table in the main query.

Note that my reading of the [relevant portion of the documentation](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_sql_tablereference.dita?lang=en) suggests that the entire subquery could be simplified to:

```
JOIN TABLE (Foo(Fruits.name)) FooOut(descr)
ON ....
```

The issue is problem 1, and how RDBMSs work.

SQL as a language is designed to operate on *sets*, that is, groups of matching records.  There's a number of reasons for this, but the catch is that most people don't really think about mathematical sets, because it's not something they're used to.  When you `(INNER) JOIN` one table to another, you're saying "get me all rows in `table_a`, and multiply by all (include the row in `a` for each) matching rows in `table_b`.

The problem is I'm not exactly sure what sets will be generated due to the use of the function.  However, I think you should probably be able to get away with something like this:

```
SELECT Fruits.name, FooOut.descr 
FROM Schema.Fruits
CROSS JOIN TABLE (Foo(Fruits.name)) FooOut(descr)
```

The difference between an `(INNER) JOIN` and a `CROSS JOIN` is that no correlation (the `ON` clause) is allowed with a `CROSS JOIN` - all rows in `table_a` will be multiplied by all rows in `table_b`.  Here's the fun part - the rows in `table_b` (the table generated by the function) should only *exist* for the relevant rows in `table_a` in this case (the matching `Schema.Fruits` row).

If this doesn't work, you may need to change the output of `Foo(...)` to include an additional column in the result table, comprised solely of the input `Fruits.name`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understood the problem, but my guess is:

```
select x.* 
from schema.fruits as f 
cross join TABLE (schema.foo(f.name)) as x
```